# How can I connect elements inside an SVG so that when one is hidden, the next element takes it's position?

Tags: javascript, svg

[image]

I have an SVG image similar to the image shown above, this represents a flow.
The positioning along the flow is important. This means that, using the image as reference, #2 can not be shown side by side with #1 and #3 must be side by side with #2.

If an element on that flow is not visible the next element must take it's place.
So if #4 is hidden, #5 would take #4 place and the line after #4 would not be visible.

Having a new SVG file for each possible combination is not an option as it would mean thousands of files.

**What is the best way to achieve this result?**

Comment: I would code this by putting the elements on a path (the connectors). But I would need to see your code. Also the first statement in your question is not very clear.

Comment: Hey @enxaneta each line on the image is a path, and each circle and number are a group composed of circle and text.I created a Pen with a simple example of how the code is for you to check out. https://codepen.io/marioandrade/pen/Yoppqm